# Не отображать директорию в адресе

Tags: .htaccess

На сервере (локальном) три страницы лежат в папке, выглядит это вот так:

```
\dir
  \page1.php
  \page2.php
  \page3.php
```

Следовательно и адрес сейчас такой `site.ru/dir/page1.php`

Вопрос, можно ли, оставив странице в папке, сделать некий редикт, который не будет учитывать папку и адрес к странице будет таким `site.ru/page1.php` причём для всех страниц в папке.
А если запрос будет к самой папке, т.е. `site.ru/dir`, то редикт на один из файлов, допустим `page3.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать, например, так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Запрос к файлу в корневой папке.
# При отсутствии запрошенного файла в корневой папке - транслируем
# запрос в запрос к одноименному файлу в папке /dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/\.]+\.php)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* dir/%1 [L,QSA]

# запрос непосредственно к папке - транслируем в запрос к dir/page3.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dir/?$
RewriteRule .* dir/page3.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Работает, только учитывает полное название, т.е. `/page.php`, забыл указать, но `.php` у адреса отключен)